# unix envsubst not picking local environment variables inside docker

Tags: envsubst

I've for a standard linux docker container that sets some environment variable E1=60 and installs a file `myfile` which is simply the line:

```
this is ${E1}
```

then runs the following script at container startup time:

```
#!/bin/sh
E1=80
export E1=80
cat myfile | envsubst
```

the output is:

```
this is 60
```

instead of:

```
this is 80
```

How do I make envsubst pick up my local/exported E1=80 variable?

Answer (score 0):

resolved, the issue was that there was a previous script that substituted empty vars (which I wasn't aware of) and therefore, my envsubst calls didn't find them